# Getting "TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string" while running CNN model tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-slim

I am trying to train a simple `CNN model` for classifying images. I'm trying to classify images from 5 different classes. But while training I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got

Detailed error report can be found [here](https://i.postimg.cc/FHQV5FD9/error.png)

Data directory structure

> **data2/train** contains 5 directories corresponding to each class having
>   17 images of varying resolution
>
> **data2/test** contains 5 directories corresponding to each class having 7
>   images of varying resolution

The complete code can be accessed from [here](https://gist.github.com/atinesh-s/facaec2521f7cf9eb927ee2942337092)

Comment: Go ahead and put the full stacktrace into the question, not a screenshot. Screenshots might not be accessible to all users

Comment: @C.Nivs how can I generate `full stacktrace`